# The CREATE TABLE SQL construct or statement is not supported, with ASP.NET 2008 Express

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using MS Visual Web Developer 2008 tried to run simple SQL into query to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Category] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

After executing this query, I get following error in message window:

```
The CREATE TABLE SQL construct or statement is not supported ASP.NET
```

However, the table has been created.

Can you help me why do I get this error, and why the table is created after that?

Similar error message is show on an `ALTER` statement.

Comment: CREATE TABLE <---> ASP.NET? Where are you typing this script? In a Query inside Management Studio it should work, I Suppose

Comment: Well that's why I'm asking this question

Comment: So, you're typing inside Management Studio -please answer-?

Comment: I'm typing into pane showed with Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition => Database Explorer => Right click => New Query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google Search yielded the following link:

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?428733-Create-Table-Visual-Studio-SQL-Compact-Vista

According to that thread, the most likely cause for the error is that the statement you issued cannot be represented graphically, but this does not stop the table from being created.